# Is there any difference between ee.Geometry.BBox and ee.Geometry.rectangle in google earth engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to extract sub images on google earth engine.

by using, for ex, either

```
ee.Geometry.BBox(-158.2134917611458, 21.44096975942727,-158.11696484634894, 21.621599066674218)
```

or

```
ee.Geometry.rectangle(-158.2134917611458, 21.44096975942727,-158.11696484634894, 21.621599066674218)
```

The results are similar but slightly different. I wonder if there is any difference between them

Answer (score 0):

ee.Geometry.Rectangle is geodesic:true, ee.Geometry.BBox is geodesic:false,
see attributes in console.

example script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b32d79b8c9ae8a69c5e3a16a9ec80fa3